# if preg_match finds nothing echo something

Tags: php, return, preg-match

This is my code:

```
function getaname($name)
{
    $result = file_get_contents('https://www.something.com');
    $regex = '/<div class="classname">([^<]*)<\/div>/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $result, $matches)) {   
        return $matches[1]; 
    } else{
        return 'N/A';}
}
```

This code is working perfectly when `preg_match` finds something in the `div` but I want it to `echo` or return `N/A` when it finds nothing like in the dive

```
<div></div>
```

Comment: Do you have quotes round `N/A`?

Comment: Side note, it would be a little cleaner if the function's execution was consistent, meaning that it would be better to return `false` or `NULL` instead of doing an `echo`. You are probably checking after the fact that the value returned is an array anyway so you may as well just echo in response to the return.

Comment: Well i can keep N/A in my text so if it finds nothing it doesn't return the empty div but it does ... what I want is that: if the preg_match find 0 caractere in the div it returns nothing , so the original text which is N/A stays and doesn't desepear like it does now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you don't explain the conditions exactly, I suppose you check for empty `div` which in your case is `<div class="classname"></div>`.

In this case your regexp still finds occurence of `<div class="classname">` and `preg_match` returns truthy value. So, in this case you also need to check that `$matches[1]` is not empty:

```
if (preg_match($regex, $result, $matches) && !empty($matches[1])) {
    return $matches[1]; 
} else {
    return 'N/A';
}
```

Here's a fiddle https://3v4l.org/XUvUD, uncomment `$result` lines and see the output in each case.

Or your regexp can be chaged to `$regex = '/<div class="classname">([^<]+)<\/div>/';`, see `plus` instead of `*`, which means "at least one symbol". In this case the rest of the code should not be changed. Again fiddle here https://3v4l.org/Eo1bF.